# get img attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this code so that if the `src` of the main `img` is equal to another `img's` that `img` will hide but it hides all of the `img`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mar1/ej1k50p1/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="a" >
<img src="a">
</div>

<div class="thumb">
<img src="a">
</div>

<div class="thumb b">
<img src="b">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:black;}
.thumb{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:green;}
.b{background-color:yellow;}
```

JQUERY

```
var src = $(".a img").attr('src');

if($(".thumb img").attr('src') == src ) {
$(".thumb").hide();
}
```

Comment: because `$('.thumb')` matches BOTH `class="thumb"` and `class="thumb b"`. you need to do a `.each` on the results of `$(.thumb img)` and specifically target each found img as you find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate and check each image, and only hide the one that matches

```
var src = $(".a img").attr('src');

$(".thumb").each(function() {
    if ( $('img', this).attr('src') == src ) { 
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are hiding all the `thumb` elements with:

```
$(".thumb").hide();
```

You need just the ones that match the condition, you can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(".thumb").filter(function(){
    return $('img',this).attr('src') == src
}).hide()
```

#### [Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ej1k50p1/2/)